# Chrome Devtools with no internet connection

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug a NodeJS application using the new Chrome DevTools in NodeJS 6.9.5. I can debug fine when I have an active Internet connection, but if I have to go offline the DevTools stop working. I get the blank screen I've heard mentioned. When I go to the console, it is complaining about not being able to read property 'addExtensions' of undefined. I believe it's trying to download some resource from the web and failing.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addExtensions' of undefined
    at DevToolsApiImpl._dispatchOnInspectorFrontendAPI (devtools_compatibility.js:57)
    at DevToolsApiImpl.addExtensions (devtools_compatibility.js:70)
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

Comment: Some of your extensions might be trying to make some requests. What happens when you open a Chrome window in Incognito Mode?

Comment: @KayceBasques The same thing happens in Incognito Mode.

Comment: It seems to be fixed in 7.x , but since 6.x is LTS you should definitely report it on https://crbug.com .